# How to find duplicated subsets of several sets?

Tags: python, set

I have several sets like following:

```
A={0, 2, 3, 4}

B={1, 2, 4}

C={0, 1, 5}
```

Then, I have found subsets of each set:

```
SubsetA=[{0}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 4}
         {0, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}]

SubsetB=[{1}, {2}, {4}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 2, 4}]

SubsetC=[{0}, {1}, {5}, {0, 1}, {0, 5} {1, 5}, {0, 1, 5}]
```

What I would like to do is to find duplicated subsets then remove them from the final output. For instance, the output of the above example is **24** since there are 24 subsets left after duplicated ones are removed like following:

```
{0}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 4}
{0, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {5}, {0, 1},
{0, 5}, {1, 5}, {0, 1, 5}
```

I am able to find all subsets by using python script (this finds subsets of only one set); however, I am not sure how to find duplicated subsets of several sets and remove them.

I do not need to generate these subsets. Instead, I need to find just the number 24 as in the above example.

Note: I have at most 4 sets with sizes range from 15 to 35 as following:

```
A={32, 33, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31}

B={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41}

C={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 35, 43}

D={34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48}
```

Is there any suggestion?

my subset code:

```py
def subsetsUtil(A, subset, index): 
    print(*subset) 
    for i in range(index, len(A)):  

        # include the A[i] in subset.  
        subset.append(A[i]) 

        # move onto the next element.  
        subsetsUtil(A,subset, i + 1)  

        # exclude the A[i] from subset and  
        # triggers backtracking. 
        subset.pop(-1)  
    return

    # below function returns the subsets of vector A.  
def subsets(A): 
    global res 
    subset = [] 

    # keeps track of current element in vector A  
    index = 0
    subsetsUtil(A, subset, index)  

    # Driver Code 

    # find the subsets of below vector.  
    array = [0, 2, 3, 4]

    # res will store all subsets.  
    # O(2 ^ (number of elements inside array))  
    # because at every step we have two choices  
    # either include or ignore.  
    subsets(array)
```

Comment: You get all unique subsets of a certain set. Then you perform this on multiple sets. Is you goal to find the unique subsets from all the subsets you get?

Comment: Yes exactly, my goal is to find unique subsets from all the subsets.

Comment: What do you mean by unique? Because it usually means "exists in exactly one place". But looking at your example do you mean all subsets (without repeating) - as in, like, set of subsets?

Comment: Do you want the subsets that are not in any other set of subsets? Or simply all the subsets, without repetitions?

Comment: From the output it looks like he wants union of all the subsets of A,B,C.

Comment: `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), (set(itertools.combinations(s, i)) for s in (A, B, C) for i in range(len(s)+1)))`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `{1}` is in the list of unique subsets.

Comment: Since you want only the number: Would it be feasible to generate all subsets, combine those and count, or are we talking about _really big_ numbers here?

Comment: I edited my post. What I want is to find duplicated subsets. And yes some numbers are really big so my python script is running for hours.

Comment: I'm getting mixed signals here. So, do you want just the numbers (because they can be really large), or the actual subsets (as you need to know the duplicates)? And do you really want the unique ones or the duplicates (dupes might be easier to find)

Comment: @tobias_k I need to find duplicated subsets. Then I will remove them from the all subset list and count the remaining ones. This is 23 in my above example. What I only need is this 23.

Comment: @HeapOverflow In my worst case, I have 4 sets with sizes range from 15 to 35.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I have already added.

Comment: @HeapOverflow it is already there also

Comment: Thanks (though I wouldn't say "already" when you added it *after* I asked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write that some of your sets have 35 elements, which would mean that they have ~34 *billion* subsets. Generating, merging and counting all those subsets is not really an option.
If you just need the number of total subsets, and not the subsets themselves, you could calculate the number of subsets of each individual set as 2<sup>n</sup>-1 and combine those for all combination of 1, 2, 3, ... sets.

```
>>> sets = [{0, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
>>> num_subsets = lambda s: 2**len(s) - 1
>>> [num_subsets(s) for s in sets]
[15, 7, 7, 31]
# "naive" solution for reference
>>> len(set(frozenset(c) for s in sets for i in range(1, len(s)+1)
...                      for c in combinations(s, i)))
...
42
# combining subset counts of combinations of sets
>>> sum((-1)**k * sum(num_subsets(reduce(set.intersection, s))
...                   for s in combinations(sets, k+1)) 
...     for k in range(len(sets)))
...
42
```

The idea is to count all the subsets of individual sets, and then getting the subsets of all pairwise intersections of sets (i.e. the duplicate subsets) and subtracting those from the first. Since those could again have duplicates if e.g. one or more element appears in three sets, we have to get the intersection of *three* sets next and *add* those to the result again, then subtract the subsets of intersections of four, and so on. This is done with the `(-1)**i` factor.

Of course, this pretty uselessly calculates *all* the combinations of N sets, even if there can not be any intersection between them (don't have to check the intersection `A & B & X` if `A & B` already is the empty set), so you could expand this to only go "deeper" if the current selection of sets still has common elements, but that's left as an exercise to the interested reader. (But if you have "at most 4 sets" anyway, then that's really not necessary.)

---

Note that while the "naive" approach (generating all the subsets and collecting them in a set) has its complexity in the "generating subsets" part, this algorithm has the complexity in the "finding intersections of combinations of sets" part. Thus, in your case, with few sets with many elements, this algorithm is much faster then the naive one, but if you had *many* sets with *few* elements each, the situation would be reversed and the naive would be much faster.

```
>>> gen_sets = lambda n, m: [{random.randint(0,2*n) for _ in range(n)}
...                          for _ in range(m)]
...    
>>> sets = gen_sets(15, 10) # few sets, many elements
>>> %timeit naive()
10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop
>>> %timeit this()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.73 ms per loop

>>> sets = gen_sets(10, 15) # many sets, few elements
>>> %timeit naive()
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop
>>> %timeit this()
10 loops, best of 3: 162 ms per loop
```

If both the number of elements and number of sets is large(-ish), the above mentioned optimization might help, but even then it is trivial to construct cases where no intersections can be pruned, e.g. if all the sets share a common element.

Comment: Just what I was writing, except I didn't get the `(-1)^k` bit right... One possible minor improvement would be to reuse the intersections between iterations of `k`.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, that's kind of what I'm hinting to in the last paragraph. Think a recursive algo would work well here. Feel free to expand on this point.

Comment: OP added a worst case to the question now, you could run your solution on that.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Sure. But in this case, the answer is _not_ 42 but 34,628,238,845, which just does not have the same ring to it. ;-)

Comment: :-D Well I meant additionally, since you probably also wouldn't be able to verify it with the naive solution. Just to demonstrate how fast your solution can do it.

Comment: I _think_ this would work to reuse intersections: `total = sum(map(num_subsets, sets)); sets_k = enumerate(sets); for k in range(1, len(sets)): { sets_k = [(i + j + 1, sk & s) for i, sk in sets_k for j, s in enumerate(sets[i + 1:])]; total += (1 - 2 * (k % 2)) * sum(num_subsets(s) for _, s in sets_k) }`

Comment: @tobias_k thanks a lot, both methods are working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a a possible solution:

```
from itertools import combinations

sets = [{0, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 5}]
result = set(frozenset(c)
             for s in sets
             for i in range(len(s)+1)
             for c in combinations(s, i))
```

My solution includes also the empty set.

Comment: OP said they want only the number of unique subsets. The reason _might_ be that the number is far too large to generate them all in this way.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, I'll try to think about a more efficient solution

Answer (score 2):

Just use... `set` if you want to find unique elements!

```
tot = set((frozenset(i) for i in SubsetA +SubsetB+SubsetC))
print(len(tot))
```

gives `23`

I had to use `frozenset` because as a set is a mutable type it is not hashable and cannot be used in a set or as a key in a dict. If you want a list of plain sets, just use another comprehension:

```
print([set(i) for i in tot])
```

gives:

```
[{0, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 2, 4}, {5}, {0, 1, 5}, {3}, {0}, {0, 5}, 
 {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 3}, {0, 2}, {2}, {0, 1}, {0, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {4}, 
 {0, 3}, {2, 4}, {0, 3, 4}, {1, 4}, {1}]
```

Comment: This is also not an efficient solution (it is basically identical to my answer). Any idea how we can improve it?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco: To be honest, I had no idea of the real problem, so I just just try to propose a simple a direct way and explain it. But when I have to find duplicates in Python I use a set. Full stop. And if there are performance problems, then I simply do not use Python (at least for the most time consuming parts). Said differently I have no idea nor even start point for a better way

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. You just need to combine all the subsets you get into a single list, where a subset is represent with a tuple.

```
sets = [(6,5), (4,5), (5,6), (6,5)]

sets_sorted = list(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)),sets))
unique_sets = list(set(sets_sorted))
# Unique sets: [(4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Basically you sort the `tuple` if the same numbers appear in a different order in a subset and then you convert them back to `tuple`. This is needed in order for `set` to remove the duplicates, because a `tuple` is a hashable type.
Tuples are then put into a `set` which removes the duplicates and then converted back to a `list`. Then you can access them or get their count by `len(unique_sets)`.